# Binding a value for mat-form-field Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

As I'm doing a beginner angular project I ran into this error.
ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.

my component.ts file

saveVideoDetailsForm: FormGroup;
title: FormControl = new FormControl('');

my html file

```
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Title</mat-label>
    <input matInput [formControl]="title" required />
  </mat-form-field>
```

tried various fixes but failed fix this error

Comment: did you import MatInputModule to your module?

Comment: You need to import, imports: [MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule] in the module where you component is declared or in the import of your component if it's a standalone component (option standalone: true in the component)